# How to disable UIButton highlight when pressed in a nib file?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, nib

I have a `UIButton` inside a `UIView` in a nib file and I want to disable the highlight when the button is pressed.

However unchecking the box (for all states) 'Highlighted Adjust Image' in Interface Builder for the button doesn't remove the highlight.

I have also tried to disable the highlight programmatically with in an @IBAction:

```
@IBAction func myButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
}
```

But the highlight is still here when the button  is pressed.

**How to disable the highlight when none of the above methods work?**

Comment: Make sure your `UIButton` type is set to custom.

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` your `UIButton` type should be set to custom.